# Passing object in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am writing a generic readRecords() function in which I want to pass a filter variable. This filter variable could by anything. In angularjs, I could have written:

```
var filter = {
   'order_type': 'new',
   'city_id': 5
}

readRecords(filter)
```

And the function readRecords() will be like:

```
function readRecords(filter){
}
```

As I understand in typescript, we need to specify type of data. So, I guess I have to write like this:

```
let filter = {
   'order_type': 'new',
   'city_id': 5
}

readRecords(filter)

function readRecords(filter: ?){
}
```

**What data type should I specify for filter as it may have any number of keys?**

Its easy to write create() function as we can specify a type to create:

```
create(record: T): Observable<T>{
    return this.httpClient.post<T>(url, record).map(data => this.serializer.fromJson(data) as T);
}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: `any`................

Comment: If your filter has no structure whatsoever, just define it as `any` or `Object`. Otherwise, build a `Filter` interface for it

Comment: oh yes, any will do, thanks

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the implementation of `readRecords`.